# Iniciante em Python, else e elif

Tags: python

```
idade = int(input("Insira sua idade:")) 
if(idade<=0): 
  print("Sua idade nao pode ser 0 ou menos de zero") 
elif(idade>150): 
   print("sua idade nao pode ser maior de 150 anos") 
elif(idade<18):
   print("voce precisa ter mais de 18 anos")
```

Por que não posso usar `elif` em tudo? Exemplo: `elif(idade<=0):`

Comment: `if` é "se", `elif` é "ou se". Sem o `if` não tem o `elif`.

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa entender o fluxo das coisas.

#### `if`

Executa um bloco de código **se** determinada condição for atendida.

#### `elif`

É uma abreviação para `else if`. Ou seja, `senão, e se` ou `caso contrário, e se`.
Executa um determinado bloco de código **apenas** se a condição do `if` (ou `elif`) anterior à ele não for atendida e a condição dele próprio for.

#### `else`

Executa determinado bloco de código se todas as condições anteriores não forem atendidas.

Traduzindo seu código para um pseudo-linguagem em português

```
se(idade <= 0)
    print("Sua idade nao pode ser 0 ou menos de zero") 
caso contrário, e se (idade > 150)
    print("sua idade nao pode ser maior de 150 anos") 
caso contrário, e se (idade < 18)
    print("voce precisa ter mais de 18 anos")
caso contrário
    print('Nenhuma condição atendida')
```

Answer (score 3):

A primeira condição sempre será um **IF** chamado no começo da estrutura condicional, logo após ele você pode acrescentar quantos **ELIF** forem necessários.

Recomendo que de uma olhada em estruturas condicionais em algum livro de lógica de programação.

Segue um link para entender melhor essa parte: http://www.dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/estrutura-de-decisao-se-entao-senao/

Answer (score 3):

Cara, se eu entendi você está com dúvida sobre os blocos  de controle **if/else**. Teoricamente, em quase todas as linguagens de programação, você tem que ter uma condição inicial com `if`, as outras com `elif` (no caso do python mas em algumas outras é `else if`) e a última, caso nenhuma outra for atendida, com o `else`.
Ou seja,

```
Se algo (if): isso
Se não, se algo (elif): aquilo
Se não, se algo (elif): aquilo outro
Se nenhuma das anteriores (else): aquilo final
```

Bom, esse é o padrão, mas nada impede que você coloque só `elif`. Desde que eles consigam cobrir todos os casos não tem problema, porém você não está programando seguindo os padrões.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa de um if para usar um elif. entenda da seguinte forma:

o seu código de uma forma NÃO Pythônica ficaria assim:

```
idade = int(input("Insira sua idade:")) 
if(idade<=0): 
  print("Sua idade nao pode ser 0 ou menos de zero") 
else:
    if(idade>150): 
         print("sua idade nao pode ser maior de 150 anos") 
    else:
         if(idade<18):
              print("voce precisa ter mais de 18 anos")
```

O que o Python faz é simplificar essa estrutura para enxugar o código. Logo, partindo do princípio que o ELIF é uma forma simplificada de um Else seguido de If, não há porque utilizar um elif de cara sem ter usado, antes, um if.

Answer (score 1):

Só para complementar a resposta, o código correto seria:

```
idade = int(input("Insira sua idade:")) 
if idade<=0:
   print("Sua idade nao pode ser 0 ou menos de zero")
elif idade<18:
   print("voce precisa ter mais de 18 anos")
elif idade>150:
   print("sua idade nao pode ser maior de 150 anos") 
else:
   print("Perfeito")
```

Um conceito correto é sempre ter as condições `IF` por ordem de exclusão, ex: do menor pro maior, do maior pro menor..então começamos verificando números negativos, depois menores que 18 e depois se são maiores que 150 e caso não for nenhum perfeito.

E claro, sempre começa um bloco de condição (`if`) com `IF`, depois poderá usar o `ELSE` ou `ELSE IF` (No caso do python `else if = ELIF`)
Isso é uma característica de programação que todas as linguagens seguem!.